# Ignite query result fetched from cache or disk

Tags: ignite

With Ignite Native Persistence enabled, is there a way to know if the query result is being fetched from cache or disk?

I am using **Apache Ignite 2.7.5** with 2 nodes running in **PARTITIONED** mode with the following configuration at each node.

```
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <!-- Redefining the default region's settings -->
                <property name="pageSize" value="#{4 * 1024}"/>
                <!--<property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>-->
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{105L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                        <!--Setting the size of the default region to 4GB. -->
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{120L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize"
                                  value="#{4096L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <!--<property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>-->
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data is stored in so-called pages located in off-heap memory, it could be either a RAM or a disk, though, for the latter Ignite needs to load pages to the off-heap first, and it doesn't perform reads from a disk directly. On-heap memory is required for data processing, like merging data sets for an SQL query, processing communication requests, and so on.

There is no solid way of detecting if a piece of required data was already preloaded into RAM, though there are some metrics that could help you to see what's happening to the cluster in general. I.e. how often page eviction happens and so on.

You might want to check the following metrics for a data region.

These three give an estimate of the data size loaded to a data region:

- TotalAllocatedPages
- PagesFillFactor
- EmptyDataPages

When persistence is enabled, these provide information on how intensively we use disk for reads (smaller is better):
​

- PagesReplaceRate
- PagesRead
- PagesReplaced

Some implementation details that might be useful:
[Ignite Durable Memory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Ignite+Durable+Memory+-+under+the+hood), [Ignite Persistent Store - under the hood](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Ignite+Persistent+Store+-+under+the+hood)

Comment: Are there any commands that I can run on ignite node to find `PagesReplaceRate`, `PagesRead`, `PagesReplaced` ?

Comment: You can check it from the code directly like: `ignite.dataRegionMetrics()` -> `mm.getPagesFillFactor()` or using  DataRegionMetricsMXBean https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/monitoring-metrics/metrics#monitoring-ram-memory-usage. Note, that most likely you need to enable metrics collection explicitely.

Comment: Hey Alexandr, we are not using gridgain community edition for ignite. We are using apache ignite 2.7.5. Can these monitoring features, mentioned on gridgain page, be used in apache ignite 2.7.5?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. CE and Ignite should be interchangeable, this metric should definitely be available for Ignite 2.7.5, though you might be right, something related to metrics might have been revoked in 2.9.0. I think it's better to create a separate question if you won't find them.

Comment: Please help here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125071/apache-ignite-2-7-5-monitoring-metrics